# Source for Interferometer experiments with single photons

Tags: photons, resource-recommendations, interferometry

The Phys.SE question [Single Photon Single Slit Interferometry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/225608/) is about the results of such experiments. What I’m interested is to read about interferometer experiments with single shooted photons. Who carried out such experiments?

Comment: It is not too difficult to perform such experiments, but it is not very interesting. Therefore, there is not much motivation for experimenters in this field to perform them. Or do you have a context for such experiments that would make it interesting?

Comment: @flippiefanus The context see here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368333/when-light-reflects-off-a-mirror-does-the-wave-function-collapse/372068#372068. I was very surprised, how the interferometer handles the light beams.

Comment: @flippiefanus And this question is somehow related too https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362598/michelson-interferometer-with-and-without-gaussian-beam

Comment: I still don't see the interesting aspect here. Interferometers may be fascinating, but they are generally well understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not very comprehensive, John Townsend gives some basic references in the first chapter of his spiffy book *Quantum Physics A fundamental approach to modern physics*. (The first chapter examines a simplified quantum model of light remenicient of Feynman's pop-sci book on QED.)

- **Demonstrating that reliable single photon counting is possible** P. Grangier, G. Roger, and A. Aspect, *Europhys. Lett.* **1**, 173 (1986)
- **Basic Mach-Zender interferometry with single photons** A. Aspect, P. Grangier, and G. Roger. *J. Optics (Paris)* **20**, 119 (1989)
- **Delayed choice in a Mach_Zender interferometer** V. Jacques, E. Wu, et. al *Science*, **315** 988 (2007)

(The bold type is my interpretation of the reason the papers are referenced rather than titles, BTW.)

That is pretty sparse but it represents a starting point for a more comprehensive literature search.